# Does Fluent-NHibernate support mapping to procedures?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, stored-procedures, fluent-nhibernate, enterprise-library

I've been wondering if it's possible to have Fluent-NHibernate communicate with stored procedures that already exist and assign mapping from the result set to my own domain objects.

Also is Fluent-NHibernate able to directly execute procedures with no result set returned?

Basically I've been considering the implications of using Fluent-NHibernate to replace a dated TypedDataSet model with a domain driven design that can return simple objects from the DAL. If Fluent-NHibernate cannot work with SPs easily, I think I would most likley have a combinational DAL that will take advantage of FNH for simple CRUD operations while leaving complex procedures to be managed by Enterprise Library. While I don't think it would be optimal to have 2 competing DALs if FNH cannot play well with SPs I'd love to hear any other ideas than using both EntLib and FNH together.

Comment: @Gregory I took a look at your blog and honestly i don't know, I've had a falling out with NHibernate/FNH and have kept up anything coming out of them. This seems like it would be a good question to open on stack overflow though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trunk version of Fluent NHibernate (on GitHub) supports insert, update and delete stored procedures.

In your mapping class constructor, call:

```
SqlInsert("StoredProcName");
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this myself yet, but it certainly will come in handy soon.

For more info see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/44cd2963145f327) in the Fluent NHibernate Google Group.

Comment: Nice to know of course those are far less useful than the select procedures but I guess that gets into alot more weirder programming.

Comment: Yes... the current implementation isn't very useful. In any case for FNH to fully support (*sob*) CRUD stored procedures it still needs to add support for the "loader" and "sql-query" elements. But I don't think there's been any progress there.

Answer (score 11):

Just to answer my own question, the answer is no other than you can write xml mapppings for NHibernate and combine them with Fluent-NHibernate mappings. SP mapping for FNH will most likely be added later.