# Anyone know of any decent resources on Stored Procedures for Fluent Nhibernate 1.1

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent

A recent release of Fluent Nhibernate (1.1) now supports stored procedures. I was wondering if anyone out there has found any good blog articles on how to do this!

**I am not asking about** using classic hbm mappings instead which these questions previously asked:

[Does Fluent-NHibernate support mapping to procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296732/does-fluent-nhibernate-support-mapping-to-procedures)

[Fluent NHibernate and Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637862/fluent-nhibernate-and-stored-procedures)

The documentation via the following links I cannot seem to access:

http://support.fluentnhibernate.org/discussions/help/18-stored-procedure
John Peterson's blog entry does not seem to work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I guess in the interim I could use the old hbm mapping approach - but I'd rather use fluent nhibernate if I can.

Comment: Ok update that link to the support forum is working - but is not of any direct use - will experiment further..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help you a bit:

> Unfortunately the current support for
>   using stored procedures is via the 
>   SqlInsert, SqlUpdate, SqlDelete
>   methods. None of those are applicable
>   to  using a stored procedure to a do a
>   select.

http://support.fluentnhibernate.org/discussions/help/172-stored-procedures-in-fluentnhibernate-11